Confusion about the covariance $r(t)$ and positive definiteness
I am reading the paper Asymptotic Properties of the Maximum in a Stationary Gaussian Process by James Pickands which is concerned with the asymptotic properties of maxima of stationary Gaussian processes. Letting $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ denote a centered stationary unit-variance Gaussian process, Pickands assumes that the covariance kernel $r(t)=\operatorname{Cov}(X_{s+t},X_s)$ satisfies
\begin{equation}
r(t)=1-C|t|^\alpha+o(|t|^\alpha)
\end{equation}
as $t\to0$ where $C>0$ and $\alpha\in(0,2]$.
Confusion: He claims that a covariance function $r$ cannot satisfy the above equation with $\alpha>2$, as $r(t)$ would not be positive definite in this case. But does not claim as to why?
Does anyone know why $r(t)$ is not positive definite if $\alpha>2$?

Sorry, but what is the $r$?

The function $r$ is the covariance function, i.e., $r(t)=\operatorname{Cov}(X_{s+t},X_s)$.

Ah yes, I see, my mistake!

Hint: use the Bohner theorem. Notice that using the inverse Fourier transform of your function, you should obtain the function which is positive at any point.
